# Receive multiple parameters from API with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a script which is going to receive six parameters from API.
I'm using [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data) for receive a cryptocurrency data.

Don't look on `schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *'` this is a [Node-Schedule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) and it's just calling the script every second.

**CODE**

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    var burl = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1";

    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ourRequest.open('GET', burl, true);
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var x1 = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText)
        var btcdata = (x1)
        console.log(btcdata);
        saveToDatabase(btcdata);
    }
    ourRequest.send();
});
```

This code is automatically receive a data from API every second.

Goal: How can I specify the request in `var btcdata = (x1)` currently I receive whole array in my console. I need only this five  parameters(took them from Binance API documentation.)

I was trying to make request something like - `var btcdata = (x1.open)`
Doesn't work for me.

```
"0.01634790",       // Open
"0.80000000",       // High
"0.01575800",       // Low
"0.01577100",       // Close
"148976.11427815",  // Volume
```

**FULLCODE**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;


var today = new Date();

var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();

var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;



var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    var burl = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1";

    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ourRequest.open('GET', burl, true);
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var x1 = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText)
        var btcdata = (x1)
        console.log(btcdata);
        saveToDatabase(btcdata);
    }
    ourRequest.send();
});

const saveToDatabase = function(BTCdata) {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
        dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

**EDIT1**

Forget to add response in my console from `var btcdata = (x1.open)`

```
[
  [
    1591855200000,
    '9887.15000000',
    '9889.89000000',
    '9758.00000000',
    '9821.37000000',
    '4752.42857100',
    1591858799999,
    '46642291.56191164',
    39400,
    '2037.49498800',
    '19997525.53467965',
    '0'
  ]
]
```

**EDIT2**
This is response in Chrome console.
[image]

Comment: You can do a post request and accept values as a part of `req.body`? don't understand what `* * * * * *` is supposed to do either.

Comment: Is `schedule.scheduleJob` an express route middleware?

Comment: @pai.not.pi * * * * * * is a node-schedule package which calls the script every second. The main problem is in specifying the request to receive correct parameters. I don't need all of them.

Comment: @pai.not.pi I add second edit with a response from chrome console, can you take a look on it?

Comment: if it's a node middleware then the callback function should receive `req` and `res` as parameters, can you see if that has the data?

Comment: @pai.not.pi If I did it correctly. Then it doesn't has the data. I added full code in my main question, hope it helps to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in changing the method of receiving the data.

Below is the working solution.I use `fetch` and `parseFloat`

```
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function() {

     fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1')
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => {
             const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                 return { Open: parseFloat(d[1]), High: parseFloat(d[2]), Low: parseFloat(d[3]), Close: parseFloat(d[4]), Volume: parseFloat(d[5]) }
             });
             console.log(btcusdtdata);
             saveToDatabase(btcusdtdata);
         })
 });
```

If anyone got a better/cleaner code solution. I kindly welcome to edit the code accordingly. Otherwise it's a working example.

Answer (score 0):

From binance docs, `GET /api/v3/klines` - candlesticks API does not support specifying fields to be returned in response.

Response body is like

```
  [
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

what you can do is extract what you need from this array, which is elements at index 1 to 5 of inner array.

```
    var btcDataClean = btcdata[0].slice(1, 6);

    /** console.log(btcDataClean)
      [ '9831.62000000',
       '9834.11000000',
       '9795.04000000',
       '9806.37000000',
       '1769.79489500' ]

      console.log(btcdata)
      [ 1591858800000,
       '9831.62000000',
       '9834.11000000',
       '9795.04000000',
       '9806.37000000',
       '1769.79489500',
       1591862399999,
       '17367257.35561939',
       20217,
       '741.22398400',
       '7274727.13892692',
       '0' ]

    */
```

Answer (score 0):

If the API doesn't provide a way to specify which information you want, then you will receive the whole data.

If the order of the data never changes, you can use extract the desired data and assigned it to different variables.

Example:

```
const data = [
  [
    1591858800000,
    "9831.62000000",
    "9834.11000000",
    "9795.04000000",
    "9813.60000000",
    "1683.36217700",
    1591862399999,
    "16519264.41391297",
    19154,
    "705.57603000",
    "6924984.32761823",
    "0"
  ]
];

const [first, second, , ,fifth] = [...data[0]];
console.log(`First value: ${first}`); // Output: "First value: 1591858800000"
console.log(`Second value: ${second}`); // Output: "Second value: 9831.62000000"
console.log(`Fifth value: ${fifth}`); // Output: "Fifth value: 9813.60000000"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment